# Create a Pivot table in R same as that of excel pivot table

Tags: r, excel, pivot

I have an excel workbook with two sheets:

```
Sheet1 name = Test(source data)

Sheet2 name = Test_pivot(excel pivot table created from source data)
```

This is the input(not to be touched).

My requirement is that Sheet1 is updated daily with new records. Now I want to write code in R which will read Sheet1 daily and refresh Sheet2(excel pivot table) with the newly received data.

How can this be done via R?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You cannot drop in, offer some description, offer not coding effort and no data, and expect us to do your work for you. For that service, you should hire a consultant or post on one of the paid service bureaus. Read the help pages for SO.

Comment: I guess it would be easier to use the data wrangling tools of R than to try to convince excel to update its pivot table from outside excel. It is quite easy to create a pivot table (i.e. summarize the data) from within R and write it to excel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a whole lot of data, or any, in your example.  Anyway, here is a generic example of how to run a pivot on the connonical mtcars dataset.

```
library(rpivotTable)
data(mtcars)
rpivotTable(mtcars,rows="gear", cols=c("cyl","carb"),width="100%", height="400px")
```

[image]

See the links below for additional ideas of how to use pivots in R, including charting and graphing the same, and how to create pivots based on data contained in an Excel file.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpivotTable/vignettes/rpivotTableIntroduction.html

http://excel2r.com/pivot-tables-in-r-basic-pivot-table-columns-and-metrics/